# Spamassassin failing to parse config line with user_scores_custom_query rule

Tags: mysql, centos6, spamassassin

I'm trying to setup spamassassin per user config files via MySQL, and I get this error:

```
Sep  8 12:09:13.668 [12307] warn: config: failed to parse line, skipping, in "/etc/mail/spamassassin/local.cf": user_scores_custom_query SELECT preference, value FROM _TABLE_ WHERE username = _USERNAME_ OR username = '$GLOBAL' OR username = CONCAT('%',_DOMAIN_) ORDER BY username ASC
```

But I can't see wat is wrong with this config line, can someone help me?

EDIT: here is all of local.cf.

```
required_hits 5.0
report_safe 0
required_score 5
rewrite_header Subject [SPAM]

user_scores_dsn DBI:mysql:spamassassin:localhost:3306
user_scores_sql_password db_username
user_scores_sql_username db_pass
user_scores_custom_query SELECT preference, value FROM _TABLE_ WHERE username = _USERNAME_ OR username = '$GLOBAL' OR username = CONCAT('%',_DOMAIN_) ORDER BY username ASC
```

Comment: Without knowing your /etc/mail/spamassassin/local.cf nobody can help you.
Does your query run within mysql without errors?

Comment: If you take look at error you can see config line that is problematic. Yes I tried to and it worked in mysql. If you need all of local.cf lines I will paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick look at the docs I deduce this is called `user_scores_sql_custom_query` and not `user_scores_custom_query`.

Comment: Ah, i'm blind! :( Tnx dude, that was it.